# Как динамически менять файлы на странице при нажатии кнопок?

Tags: html, css

Я делаю некое подобие файлового менеджера с интерфейсом типа мейл облака.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в правой части страницы при прокликивании соответствующих кнопок открываться предпросмотр файлов (в примере будут картинки). Не совсем понимаю как это можно реализовать корректно.

```
<div class="left">
<ol class="rectangle">
  <li><a href="#">Папка 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Папка 2</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="rounded">
  <li><button>1 картинка</button></li>
  <li><button>2 картинка</button></li>
</ol>
</div>
<div class="right">
<div class="excel">
  <div class="super">
  </div>
  <iframe src="https://crosti.ru/patterns/00/15/34/73d5a298eb/picture.jpg" width="100%"
    height="700"></iframe>
 </div>
</div>
```

Как здесь можно сделать что бы при нажатии на кнопку появлялась другая картинка

Comment: Наверно надо какой то язык програмирования который умеет читать файловую систему, получаем список файлов с названиями записываем это куда то, в json например, на js читаем его и формируем обычный выпадающий список или модальное окно...показываем его по hover или click

Comment: @КанистраКанистрова, т.е. Вы хотите сделать так, чтобы в левой части экрана были кнопки: например, фото 1, фото 2, фото 3 и т.д., при нажатии на кнопку, в правой части экрана открывалась соответствующая фотография?

Comment: @darinkapoznyak да, вы очень верно меня поняли

Comment: @КанистраКанистрова, могу предложить Вам такой вариант: https://codepen.io/darinka-poznyak/pen/JjwajxG на html, css js. Если, конечно, я Вас полностью правильно поняла... Нажимаете на кнопку "картинка 1" (кнопка слева) - появляется соответствующее изображение справа. Еще раз нажимаете на кнопку - изображение исчезает. И так с остальными кнопками и изображениями. Но, над расположениями кнопок я бы смотрела в другую сторону... возможно, мой пример Вам как-то поможет)))